# passing a jquery value to php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form that display an input datepicker and a select with many choices of times, to choose a time a customer must choose at fisrt a date.

this is my code:

```
echo '<form action="my_account.php" method="post">
                Date : <input required type="text" id="datepicker" name="BIRTHDATE">';
                echo'

                <select id="slots" name="slots" >
                <option value=""></option>';
```

```js
<script>
    
    $("#slots").on("click", function() {
     
     
     if($( "#datepicker" ).val() == ''){
       
       alert('veuillez remplir le champ date en premier');
       return false;
     }else{
      var date_book = $( "#datepicker" ).val();
      alert(date_book);
      alert('champ rempli');
       $.ajax({
       type : 'POST',
       url : 'my_account.php',
       data : {
        param : date_book
       },
       success : function(data) {
        alert('ok');
       
       }
      });
      
      }     
     });
   </script>
```

And I need this variable in my sql query:

```
$start_time="09:45";
                $end_time="16:45";
                for($i = strtotime($start_time); $i<= strtotime($end_time); $i = $i + $duration * 60) {
                        $slots[] = date("H:i:s", $i);

                }   
                 echo'post param :'. $_POST['param'];
                $sql_book="select id, start, date from bookings where id_event=".$id_eve." and id_cust=".$_SESSION['id']." and date =". $_POST['param'];
                echo'sql book :'.$sql_book;
                $times=db_query($db_name,$sql_book);
                foreach($times as $time)
                {
                    if($time->id != NULL){
                        $start_book[] = $time->start;               
                        $date_book[] = $time->date;             
                    }
                }       

            for($j=0; $j < count($slots); $j++){

                echo' <option value='.$slots[$j].'">'.$slots[$j].'</option>';
            }
echo'</select>


<input type="submit" id="form_sendbutton" name="BT_Envoyer" value="Envoyer" />
</form>';
```

But the variable is not assigned to php.
Thank's for your help

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in your browser's console?

Comment: Yes I watch The Ajax response in my browser console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are sending the date in JSON format and in the PHP script, you don't decode it.

But since there is only one value... I would just remove the JSON format.

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'my_account.php',
    data : "param="+date_book,
    success : function(data) {
        alert('ok');

    }
});
```

**-----------**
**EDIT**

I worked a little on this one, since I hate to be downvoted.
Okay... My answer wasn't solving everything.

There was a lot to fix!

Well, I that think you want the `select` field to be populated with the result of the dB query, based on a date which is the result of the datepicker. *If I'm wrong on this... Just quit reading this answer right here! And try to explain what I got wrong.*
;)

**First**, you trigger you ajax call on click on the `select`... Wich is wrong.
Even if it was filled with some database result, the ajax call would be triggered on each attemps of the user to select an `option`.
So I changed it to be `onchange` of the date field.

**Then**... I wasn't wrong with my first answer. Just send the date as a `POST` value. There is no need to JSON it.

**And the most important**:
You have to create a separate PHP file for you database query.
The result will be the HTML `options` to land in the `select`.

Here is your `my_account.php`:

```
<?php
// Your PHP code before this, if any...
?>
<form action="my_account.php" method="post">
    Date : <input required type="text" id="datepicker" name="BIRTHDATE">

    <select id="slots" name="slots" ></select>
    <input type="submit" id="form_sendbutton" name="BT_Envoyer" value="Envoyer" />
</form>

<script>

$("#datepicker").on("change", function() {

    if($( "#datepicker" ).val() == ''){
        return false;
    }else{
        var date_book = $( "#datepicker" ).val();
        console.log("champ rempli "+date_book);
        $.ajax({

            type : 'POST',
            url : 'my_account_options.php',
            data : "param="+date_book,
            success : function(data) {
                console.log("ajax success");
                $("#slots").html(data);
            }
        });
    }                   
});

// Datepicker - I added this too to trigger the datepicker.
// It may be different in your code.
$('#datepicker').fdatepicker('yy-mm-dd');

</script>
```

And here is the second PHP file, which I called `my_account_options.php`:

```
<?php
if($_POST['param']){
    $start_time="09:45";
    $end_time="16:45";
    $duration=1;    // Added to test... Remove it.
    for($i = strtotime($start_time); $i<= strtotime($end_time); $i = $i + $duration * 60) {
            $slots[] = date("H:i:s", $i);

    }   
    $id_eve="someEvent";    // Added to test... Remove it.
    $_SESSION['id']="custId";    // Added to test... Remove it.
    $sql_book="select id, start, date from bookings where id_event='".$id_eve."' and id_cust='".$_SESSION['id']."' and date='". $_POST['param']."'";

    // Commented out to test...
    /*
    $times=db_query($db_name,$sql_book);
    foreach($times as $time)
    {
        if($time->id != NULL){
            $start_book[] = $time->start;               
            $date_book[] = $time->date;             
        }
    }       

    for($j=0; $j < count($slots); $j++){

        echo ' <option value="'.$slots[$j].'">'.$slots[$j].'</option>';

    }
    */

    // Added to test... Remove it.
    echo ' <option value="sql query">'.$sql_book.'</option>';
}
?>
```

**Since I don't have your database.**
I "simulated" your `$duration`, `$_SESSION['id']` and `$id_eve` vars...

Now, what is landing in the option's text here... Is your DB query for you to check it.
The result I get is this : `select id, start, date from bookings where id_event="someEvent" and id_cust="custId" and date="2016-05-05"`

Notice the double quotes wrapping the values (in the query) : It was missing.
So... In hope to be "undownvoted" (!!!) AND that this will help you.
;)


**-----------**
**EDIT**

One last thing to check...
You probably don't have the `$duration` and `$id_eve` variables in my_account_options.php.

Just set these to $_SESSION variables in my_account.php, so it could be available for your sql query... Don't forget about the `session_start();` if so.
**OR** pass them as post values like this:

```
data : "param="+date_book+"&duration=<?php echo $duration; ?>&id_eve=<?php echo $id_eve; ?>",
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply

I followed the steps that you have described to me. so I create a new php file with sql query and I replace the onclick in the select by the onchange of the input datepicker in order to have the select choices depending of the chosen date and I added the quotes to the variables in the sql queries but the select is always empty.

For information, the success ajax msg appears:

console.log("ajax success"); What i must add ???

Comment: Good... So the ajax part is solved. The problem must now be your query. Try to remove $db_name from the query connection line... As this: $times=db_query($sql_book); You'll find more details here: https://www.drupal.org/node/310072

Comment: I just see this... Check your datepicker result format. It must be separated with dashes, not backslashes, for your database. Check formating hints here : https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat I edited my answer, since I had an excedent "y" (mistyping!!) in the datepicker initialisation... Sorry for that if it was the problem ;)

Comment: I just edited again... About your "probably" missing PHP vars. ;)

Comment: Sorry i just want to specify that it works when I test the sql query with static variables, like that :    $sql_book="select id, start, date from bookings where id_event='1' and id_cust='1' and date ='2016-05-19'"; ... and i try to change the format of the date posted by: $date_b = explode("/", $_POST['param']);
$date_book=$date_b[2].'-'.$date_b[1].'-'.$date_b[0]; Apparently the script block here, it doesn t know the $_POST['param']

Comment: Ok... So no problem with the query part then. Focus on checking that you have all your variables available... Like I said, you can pass them thru SESSION or POST. Your cust_id is already a SESSION var. Check for the session_start(); to be present.

Comment: for the $id_eve and $duration, i put them in Session

Comment: this is what I added:  $date_b = explode("/", $_POST['param']);
     $date_book=$date_b[2].'-'.$date_b[1].'-'.$date_b[0];
    $sql_book="select id, start, date from bookings where id_event='".$_SESSION['id_eve']."' and id_cust='".$_SESSION['id']."'and date ='". $date_book."'";

Comment: What ? No explode! The post values are not a string. The are separate $_POST values. Retreive them like this $_POST['param'] and $_POST['date_b1'] and so on.

Comment: Now it work's for sure with dynamic variables. Thank you very much for your support